# How to create a library exposing a single Vue component that can be consumed by the distributed .mjs file?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vite

I want to create a single Vue component that gets bundled into a single .mjs file. Another Vue project can fetch this .mjs file via HTTP and consume the component. Installing the pluggable component via npm is not possible, because the other application tries to fetch it based on a configuration during runtime.

Things to consider for the pluggable component

- Might be using sub components from another UI framework / library
- Might be using custom CSS
- Might rely on other files e.g. images

---

**Reproducing the library**

I created a new Vuetify project via `npm create vuetify`

[image]

I deleted everything from the src folder except vite-env.d.ts , created a component Renderer.vue

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { VContainer } from "vuetify/components"

defineProps<{ value: unknown }>()
</script>

<template>
  <v-container>
    <span class="red-text">Value is: {{ JSON.stringify(value, null, 2) }}</span>
  </v-container>
</template>

<style>
.red-text { color: red; }
</style>
```

and an index.ts file

```
import Renderer from "./Renderer.vue";

export { Renderer };
```

I added the [library mode](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#library-mode) to the vite.config.ts

```
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: resolve(__dirname, "./src/index.ts"),
      name: "Renderer",
      fileName: "renderer",
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ["vue"],
      output: {
        globals: {
          vue: "Vue",
        },
      },
    },
  },
```

and extended the package.json file with

```
  "files": ["dist"],
  "main": "./dist/renderer.umd.cjs",
  "module": "./dist/renderer.js",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/renderer.js",
      "require": "./dist/renderer.umd.cjs"
    }
  },
```

Since I'm using custom CSS Vite would generate a styles.css file but I have to inject the styles into the .mjs file. Based on [this issue](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/1579) I'm using the plugin [vite-plugin-css-injected-by-js](https://github.com/marco-prontera/vite-plugin-css-injected-by-js).

When building I'm getting the desired .mjs file containing my custom CSS

[image]

---

**Consuming the component**

I created a new Vue project via `npm create vue`

[image]

and for testing purposes I copied the generated .mjs file right into the src directory of the new project and changed the App.vue file to

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { onMounted, type Ref, ref } from "vue";

const ComponentToConsume: Ref = ref(null);

onMounted(async () => {
  try {
    const { Renderer } = await import("./renderer.mjs"); // fetch the component during runtime

    ComponentToConsume.value = Renderer;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  } finally {
    console.log("done...");
  }
});
</script>

<template>
  <div>Imported component below:</div>
  <div v-if="ComponentToConsume === null">"still loading..."</div>
  <component-to-consume v-else :value="123" />
</template>
```

Unfortunately I'm getting the following warnings and errors

> [Vue warn]: Vue received a Component which was made a reactive object. This can lead to unnecessary performance overhead, and should be avoided by marking the component with `markRaw` or using `shallowRef` instead of `ref`.

> [Vue warn]: injection "Symbol(vuetify:defaults)" not found.

> [Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of setup function

> [Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of scheduler flush.

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: [Vuetify] Could not find defaults instance

Does someone know what I'm missing or how to fix it?

Comment: Please, post the errors as text, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors . Vuetify doesn't provide isolated components and requires the plugin to be initialized. You need to do this in main app and make sure vuetify isn't duplicated in project deps, your lib and main app use the same copy. The lib should use `vuetify` as dev dependency and specify it in `external`

Comment: I posted the errors as text, created a new main app using Vuetify and in the lib, I moved the vuetify dependency to the dev dependencies. What do you mean with `external`? I couldn't find it in the npm docs

Comment: btw. after creating a main app with Vuetify it worked fine, but yeah, I'm curious about `external` :)

Comment: I mean the thing that you already use, `external: ["vue"]`. You need to prevent the things that are global to the project from being bundled with the lib.

Comment: ah, thanks, I added `"vuetify"` to the array, still working. Do you want to post an answer?

Comment: Sure, probably will help somebody else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vuetify doesn't provide isolated components and requires the plugin to be initialized, you need to do this in main app:

```
app.use(Vuetify)
```

Make sure `vuetify` isn't duplicated in project deps, so the lib and main app use the same copy.

The lib should use `vuetify` as dev dependency and specify it in Rollup `external`, in order to prevent the things that are global to the project from being bundled with the lib:

```
external: ["vue", "vuetify"]
```